# Power BI Dax SUM

Tags: sum, dax, expression, sumifs

The result after creater DAX SUM function

[image]

Maybe I missed some steps or the system has been updated. But i have also ensured the proper relationships between tables.

[image: Please kindly view the screenshot of Tables Relationship]

I am trying to sum the total score by the category. But it resulted in the total scores of all categories.

This is the DAX that I have made

```
Total Score = sum(reaction_type[score])
```

I was expecting my DAX to produce the result where it would indicate the total score for each category.

Answer (score 0):

@Darryl Rusli, Try Grouping the category and then use sum().

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).